# Automatically add pssnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

Tags: development, powershell

I am developing in Sharepoint and I like more Windows Powershell than Sharepoint Management Shell. Every time I restart the development machine, I have to run `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell` in order to use Sharepoint cmd-lets.

How to get the machine to automatically load Sharepoint snapin when I start Windows Powershell.

Comment: create a file called `profile.ps1` in `C:Users\you\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`. When you open powershell it will run `profile.ps1` automatically. Type `Add-PSSnapin ....` to the `profile.ps1`. Note: You have to create the directory `WindowsPowerShell` in most cases

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your PowerShell shell type

```
Notepad $PROFILE
```

This will give you the scripts that is triggered for the user that is logged in.

If your profile is not created, then you can create it with this command:

```
new-item $profile -type file -force
```

here you can insert scripts that are executed before startup.

Here you can add SharePoint snapin:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0
```

I usually here set stuff like

```
Set-Strictmode -Version Latest
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$env:UserName | $env:Computername"
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
```

Comment: rask: what is this wonderful `-EA 0` parameter, undocumented ?

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` so it doesnt throw an error if module is loaded. Note that this will actually throw an error in SharePoint shell, since SharePoint **doesnt** check if module is already loaded :-(

Comment: rask: it can be usefull in .ps1 file, as I can add the snapin in the head of the file, and run the ps1 either from a naked powershell console, or a sharepoint powershell console.

Comment: When I run `notepad $profile` it says: The system cannot find the path specified. So I created this file manually and added `Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0`. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: yep, if its not created you just save it. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Sharepoint 2010, use the **SharePoint 2010 Management Shell** located at:

Start | All Programs | Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products | SharePoint 2010 Management Shell

This starts PowerShell and loads the SharePoint cmdlets. You'll probably want to Shift-Right Click this item and select "Run as administrator" from the context menu.

Note that this shortcut is only available on the SharePoint server or on a development workstation where SharePoint is installed locally.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I like Windows Powershell GUI more.

Comment: Nah, screw GUI's

Answer (score 0):

If you create a shortcut with the following command line, you'll get the snapin installed:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
```

(Obtained from [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sharepoint2010setup/thread/FCB77654-0F13-42E0-B181-6E52242FE9D6))

Comment: It works. But is there is a possibility to add it to profile ps1 or something so one doesn't need to create custom shortcuts? I like the pinned shortcut on the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Another related option is to set the value not just for the logged in user, but for **all users** on the device.  This can be done with

```
notepad $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts
```

Any code you add in here will be run for all users.  For example, adding this will automatically load the SharePoint snapin

```
If ((Get-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{ Add-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is one PowerShell script that will create the AllUsersAllHosts file if necessary and then append the Add-PSSnapIn command and then restart PowerShell or ISE and is based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/11/14/add-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-snap-in-to-all-powershell-windows.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomwis/archive/2010/01/05/enable-sharepoint-powershell-commandlets-in-the-powershell-ise.aspx).

```
if (!(test-path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts)){
    new-item -type file -path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts –force
}

$cmd = 'if((Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq
"Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) 
{ 
    Add-PSSnapIn "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" 
}'

out-file -FilePath $profile.AllUsersAllHosts -InputObject $cmd -Append

# based on http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/04/pstip-restarting-powershell-as-an-administrator/
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess,ConfirmImpact='High')]

$AsAdministrator=$false
$Force=$true

$proc = Get-Process -Id $PID
$cmdArgs = [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() | Select-Object -Skip 1

$params = @{ FilePath = $proc.Path }
if ($AsAdministrator) { $params.Verb = 'runas' }
if ($cmdArgs) { $params.ArgumentList = $cmdArgs }

if ($Force -or $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($proc.Name,"Restart the console"))
{
    if ($host.Name -eq 'Windows PowerShell ISE Host' -and $psISE.PowerShellTabs.Files.IsSaved -contains $false)
    {
        if ($Force -or $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('Unsaved work detected?','Unsaved work detected. Save changes?','Confirm'))
        {
            foreach ($IseTab in $psISE.PowerShellTabs)
            {
                $IseTab.Files | ForEach-Object {

                    if ($_.IsUntitled -and !$_.IsSaved)
                    {
                        $_.SaveAs($_.FullPath,[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
                    }
                    elseif(!$_.IsSaved)
                    {
                        $_.Save()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($IseTab in $psISE.PowerShellTabs)
            {
                $unsavedFiles = $IseTab.Files | Where-Object IsSaved -eq $false
                $unsavedFiles | ForEach-Object {$IseTab.Files.Remove($_,$true)}
            }
        }
    }

    Start-Process @params
    $proc.CloseMainWindow()
}
```