# What do I need to do in order to execute cmdlets (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: cmdlets

Need to execute an out of the box cmdlet for SharePoint 2010... but cannot for the life of me figure out how to execute them.

What am I missing?

I am trying to execute "Get-SPServiceApplication"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add SharePoint snap-in in order to use SharePoint cmdlets:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
```

After this you'll be able to use Get-SPServiceApplication and all other SharePoint cmdlets.

Also, you can consider using another scenario accessing SharePoint-ready PowerShell console: press **Start**, type *Sharepoint*, and you will see something like this:

[image]

This will execute pre-configured console, where the SharePoint snap-in is already added.

Personally I prefer even to pin the "SharePoint 2010 Management Shell" shortcut to taskbar, to have it always ready to work.

Comment: that resolved my issue - you are a gentleman and a scholor... will mark as answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Exactly. Just for additional info, if you want Sharepoint Snapin to be added automatically whenever you start Powershell, [add this command to your $PROFIlE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/automatically-add-pssnapin-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

Try typing this first:

`Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell`